# Can I create a master function in Python to take a single line of other functions?

Tags: python, higher-order-functions

I have two functions that contain mostly the same code. One returns "True" if the array passed in contains all positive numbers while the other returns "True" if the array contains all numbers that are divisible by 10.

I want to combine these two functions into a function like this:

```
def master_function(array, function):
    for i in array:
        if function:
            result = True
        else:
            result = False
            break
        print(result)
        return result
```

The only part that would vary is the "function" in the If statement. When I write functions with the missing line they don't get called as the program executes.

```
def positive_integers(array):
    i >= 0

def divisible_by_10(array):
    i%10 == 0
```

The test code isn't executed either.

```
master_function([10,20,30,35],divisible_by_10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your functions aren't returning anything, and you need to give them access to `i`:

```
def positive_integers(i):
    return i >= 0

def divisible_by_10(i):
    return not i%10

def master_function(array, function):
    for i in array:
        if function(i):
            result = True
        else:
            result = False
            break
        print(result)
        return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function don't return anything. Also, you need read about [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) and [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
def positive_integers(array):
    return all(i >= 0 for i in array)

def divisible_by_10(array):
    return all(i % 10 == 0 for i in array)

def master_function(array, function):
    return function(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def master_function(array, function):
    for i in array:
        print str(i)
        if function(i):
            result = True
        else:
            result = False
        print(result)
    return result

def positive_integers(i):
    if i >= 0:
        return True

def divisible_by_10(i):
    if i%10 == 0:
        return True

master_function([10,20,30,35],divisible_by_10)
```